# AngularJS: Requesting JSON Data with AJAX

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and Json and have a small page that needs to display data retrived from .json file in controller.
When opening the page I have error:
`Unexpected token t at Object.parse (native)...`

This is my html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Controllers/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <li>{{post.title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("PostsCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/posts.json').
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
});
```

This is .json

```
[   
    {title: "Title1"},
    {title: "Title2"},
    {title: "Title3"}
]
```

I'm not sure why I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are re parsing a json object with JSON.parse()?

or

json isnt valid

try

```
[   
    {"title": "Title1"},
    {"title": "Title2"},
    {"title": "Title3"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the reason.

Comment: @gene glad it helped, voteup and accept as an asnwer so that it can help other also :)